# Google page title not matching html <title> tag

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, html, title

I've written an online book. When I search for the book on Google, it is labeled as <no_title> rather than the title in the HTML's `<title>` tag. Any idea how I can update the title in the Google search? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Google's cached version - you can see that "<no title>" was actually the title of your page at the point it was crawled in June:

```
<title>&lt;no title&gt; &#8212; Machine Learning from Scratch</title>
```

Use Google Search Console to get Google to [re-crawl your page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en), and it will see and index the new title.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just requested re-crawling.